# Passign code as a function parameter instead of declaring a callback

Tags: c, callback

I think that some newer languages like JS can do this natively, but I forget the term for it (make a "temporary" function in-line just to pass as a callback)

What I want to do is ...

I'm writing unit tests where I set up expected input & output messages at compile time. Later at run time, I want to do some checks when each output is received or input has been processed, so I added a parameter for a callback function.

That's working fine and I could leave it & move on, but ... I am just curious ...

sometimes a function is overkill and I just need a single comparison; sometime a small block of code would do. Perhaps I could just evaluate these to a zero/non-zero value at run time? But how to pass as a parameter?

At the moment my function has the following signature

```
void AddExpectedCommand(E_peripheralType peripheral, 
                        communicationBlock_t commandBlock, 
                        errorMessage_t errorMessage, 
                        void *(*DoRunTimeChecks)(E_boolean));
```

where the final parameter is pointer to a callback function returning boolean.

Is there any way that I could pass a code expression as a parameter instead?

Or does a function seem "cleaner"?

Thanks in advance for any help ...

---

Update: oops, I got my declaration wrong.  I want to pass a pointer so a function which has no parameters and returns an e_Boolean  ... how do I do that?

Comment: The final parameter is a pointer to a callback function returning a pointer to type `void`.  A pointer to a callback function returning boolean would be `E_boolean (*DoRunTimeChecks)(E_boolean)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With C++11 you can do the following:

Function taking a function that returns a bool:

```
 void f(function<bool()>);
```

Call it with a lambda capturing a local variable:

```
 int x = ...;

 f([&x]() { return (x > 2); });
```

Or call it with some function g that returns a bool:

```
bool g();


f(g);
```

Or bind some function h that takes an int and returns a bool:

```
bool h(int x);


f(bind(h, 2));  // ie creates a nullary function from h(2)
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is called a "lambda expression" or "anonymous function."  And they don't exist in C (but do in C++ with certain qualifications).